# Why isn't Connector/Python executemany optimizing inserts?

Tags: python, mysql, connector, mysql-connector-python, executemany

I'm using Connector/Python to insert many rows into a temp table in mysql.  The rows are all in a list-of-lists.  I perform the insertion like this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor();
batch = [[1, 'foo', 'bar'],[2, 'xyz', 'baz']]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO temp VALUES(?, ?, ?)', batch)
connection.commit()
```

I noticed that (with many more rows, of course) the performance was extremely poor.  Using SHOW PROCESSLIST, I noticed that each insert was executing separately.  But the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html says this should be optimized into 1 insert.  What's going on?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html "This method executes the given database operation (query or command). The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute() returns an iterator if multi is True." There is no ? placeholder in the cursor api at all.

Comment: And yet that statement works 100% fine with '?'.  I used that because other developers used it in existing code.  It's bizarre that it *kinda* works.

Comment: The api itself supports various placeholders and perhaps some generic functionality somewhere is catching them? Either way, you can actually query the implementation itself for the place holder https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle  In the case of mysql connector, you should always use %s or the named params.

Comment: Yeah now I understand that, but I can't be the only person who's hit this. I know %s is the right placeholder but I saw all this code using ? and working fine. The *only* problem is the executemany() optimization.

Comment: I'm just hoping to help someone with the question "gosh, using question mark placeholders is fine, except executemany() isn't doing what I want". You'll see people using question-mark placeholders in python all over the place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering so other people won't go through the debugging I had to!

I wrote the query modeling it on other queries in our code that used prepared statements and used '?' to indicate parameters.  But you *can't do that* for executemany()!  It *must* use '%s'.  Changing to the following:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO temp VALUES(%s,%s,%s)', batch)
```

...led to a hundredfold speed improvement and the optimized single query could be seen using SHOW PROCESSLIST.  Beware the standard '?' syntax!

Comment: In most cases you should still use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. There are lots of other mechanisms built into mysql to facilitate bulk inserts. Most notably LOAD DATA INFILE, that would be a lot faster than your execute many

Comment: @e4c5 the statement in question quotes properly. I'm not sure what the poster was using but %s not ? is the value placeholder for the entire mysql connector cursor api.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. I know now that %s is the right placeholder, but only because '?' wasn't optimized, not because it didn't work.  ? works just fine.  That's what's such a giant pain to debug.

Comment: and I am saying you should sacrifice that speed gain for saftey since there are even faster ways to import large amounts of data

Comment: This isn't about safety.  This isn't a string format, those are placeholders.

Comment: We're not talking about what you think we're talking about. We're not talking about string formatting vs prepared placeholders. We're talking about the ? syntax I was using for placeholders vs a better syntax for placeholders.

Comment: (If you read the documentation, executemany *always* prepares its statement)

Answer (score 1):

If you used `IGNORE` like `cursor.executemany('INSERT IGNORE INTO temp VALUES(%s,%s,%s)', batch)`, `executemany()` acts just like multiple execute!

Answer (score -1):

Try turn this command on:
cursor.fast_executemany = True

Otherwise executemany acts just like multiple execute

Comment: `cursor.fast_executemany` is a pyodbc feature. This question is about MySQL Connector/Python.